# Extract number between two string in log file with awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

This is an example of log line: 
I want to find the number that appears after `callee_num:<<"` block of text and up to the next >>.

```
2016-08-21T06:37:36.830627+00:00 cccc eservice[9999]: INFO con_pr: user:<<"conxa3">> callee_num:<<"+6182290000648">> sid:<<"xxxxxxxxx160821082523657">> credits:-2.5 result:ok provider:outqtm.ym.ms
2016-08-21T06:37:42.728469+00:00 cccc eservice[32499]: INFO con_end_procr: user:conxa3 callee_num:+6182290000648 sid:xxxxxxxxx160821082523657 duration:725 result:ok provider:outqtm.ym.ms
```

Excepted result using `awk` should be `+6182290000648` from first line only.

This is what I have tried but doesn't work:

```
awk -F 'callee_num:<<" |\"' '{print $2}' filename
```

What is the correct solution? (thanks)

Comment: hey, because in the first line i have `callee_num:<<"` which is my pattern. @fedorqui

Comment: @ fedorqui thx for your comment. i have change my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with sed, using `-n` to disable printing by default:

```
sed -n 's/.*callee_num:<<"\([+0-9]*\)">.*/\1/p' file
```

When the pattern matches, the part between the double quotes is captured and used in the replacement, discarding the rest of the line.

Of course, it is possible with awk too:

```
awk 'sub(/.*callee_num:<<"/, "") && sub(/">.*/, "")' file
```

This prints any lines where the two substitutions are successful. Unlike the version using sed, it doesn't check whether the part in between the quotes is numeric. If you wanted, you could add in a further check like this:

```
awk 'sub(/.*callee_num:<<"/, "") && sub(/">.*/, "") && /^[+0-9]+$/' file
```

This ensures that after the two substitutions are made, all that you are left with is a mixture of `+` and digits from 0 to 9.

The problem with your attempt using awk is that your field separator can be `"`, which would make the second field `conxa3`.

Comment: Just one question in your sed, what is `\1`?

Comment: `\1` is a back-reference, which refers to the first group captured within the parentheses in the search pattern.

Comment: Using the expression in your `sed` command, you can also call `awk` with `match` and say: `awk 'match($0, /callee_num:<<\"([0-9+]*)\">>/, res) {print res[1]}' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah but I think that the matches array is a GNU extension. I was trying to only use standard features :)

Comment: Yes, the 3rd argument (the one that captures the groups) is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po 'callee_num:<<"\K\+\d+' file.txt
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/.* callee_num:<<"(\+[[:digit:]]+)".*/\1/p' file.txt
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0, /.* callee_num:<<\"(\+[0-9]+)\".*"/, a) {print a[1]}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
2016-08-21T06:37:36.830627+00:00 cccc eservice[9999]: INFO con_pr: user:<<"conxa3">> callee_num:<<"+6182290000648">> sid:<<"xxxxxxxxx160821082523657">> credits:-2.5 result:ok provider:outqtm.ym.ms
2016-08-21T06:37:42.728469+00:00 cccc eservice[32499]: INFO con_end_procr: user:conxa3 callee_num:+6182290000648 sid:xxxxxxxxx160821082523657 duration:725 result:ok provider:outqtm.ym.ms

% grep -Po 'callee_num:<<"\K\+\d+' file.txt
+6182290000648

% sed -nE 's/.* callee_num:<<"(\+[[:digit:]]+)".*/\1/p' file.txt
+6182290000648

% awk 'match($0, /.* callee_num:<<\"(\+[0-9]+)\".*"/, a) {print a[1]}' file.txt    
+6182290000648
```

Comment: Do u mean with `awk` it's not possible? @heemayl

Comment: @heemayi match doesn't work. `awk: bailing out at source line 1`

Comment: @MaryamPashmi you must be using Solaris. In such case, use this awk --> /usr/xpg4/bin/awk to have a proper version.

Comment: ok. I have os mac , BTW, thx sed was working with my version.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another awk:

```
$ awk '$7 ~ /<<\"/ {gsub(/.*<<"|">>$/, "", $7); print $7}' file
+6182290000648
```

The callee number is in the 7th field (ie. `awk '{print $7}' file` would output):

```
callee_num:<<"+6182290000648">>
callee_num:+6182290000648
```

If the `<<"` is found in that field (`$7 ~ /<<\"/`), truncate to and from the double quotes in that field: <s>`callee_num:<<"`</s>`+6182290000648`<s>">></s>

Comment: I don't get why u have used `gsub`?

Comment: `sub`stops after first match, `gsub` doesn't. You have to truncate from the beginning and the end. There are two matches in that `gsub()` separated by a `|` (logical OR).

Answer (score 0):

By giving 2 field separators seperated by `|`, you tell `awk` to use either one as delimiters.

So when `awk` looks for either `callee_num:<<"` or `"` and since it finds `"` before `conxa3` and again after this string. Hence, your output will be `conxa3`. In short, your `awk` command is similar to:

```
$ awk -F '"' '{print $2}' /tmp/t
conxa3
```

If you are sure that your string is going to be same, you can instead print `$4`:

```
$ awk -F '"' '{print $4}' /tmp/t
+6182290000648
```

Or you can use `sub` function of `awk` as described by other answer posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '{split( $0,a,"callee_num:<<|>>") } {gsub(/"/,"",a[3]);print a[3]}' filename
 +6182290000648
```